# Projection drift when rendering in WebGL over Google Map

Tags: google-maps, webgl, vertex-shader, map-projections

I am trying to implement a WebGL-based rendering on Google Map (api3) as I want to render a massive amount of dynamic geometries.

Basically, I create a google.maps.OverlayView attached with a WebGL canvas into the map.

However, I encountered some problem with the mapping of the projection. Basically, I extracted the "fromLatLngToPoint" function from the googlemap api as follows:

```
function fromLatLngToPoint(a){
        var c={x:0,y:0},
        d=this.j;

        c.x=d.x+a.lng*this.B;

        var e=oe(m.sin(re(a.lat)),-(1-1E-15),1-1E-15);

        c.y=d.y+.5*m.log((1+e)/(1-e))*-this.F;
        return c
}

function oe(a,b,c){null!=b&&(a=m.max(a,b));null!=c&&(a=m.min(a,c));return a}

function re(a){return m.PI/180*a}
```

Then I implemented it in my vertex shader based on the documentation in [Google Map Coordinates](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#MapCoordinates).

Basically, I have a event listener to send the updated projection constants, the viewport bounds, and the zoom level to my shader.

Then my shader will calculate the new screen coordinates based on these inputs.

```
    highp float e, x, y, offsetY, offsetX;

    // projection transformation for target points
    e = sin(p.y* PI/180.0);
    y = prj_y + 0.5 * log((1.0+e)/(1.0-e))*(-F);
    x = prj_x + p.x*B;

    // projection transformation for offset (bounds)
    e = sin(bound_y*PI/180.0);
    offsetY = prj_y + 0.5 * log((1.0+e)/(1.0-e))*(-F);
    offsetX = prj_x + bound_x*B;

    // calculate actual pixel coord wrt zoom/numTiles
    x = (x* numTiles - offsetX* numTiles);
    y = (y* numTiles - offsetY* numTiles);  

    gl_PointSize = 5.0;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(x,y,0.0,1.0);
```

However, as shown in the screenshot below, it seems there are some errors? The rendered geometries are distorted. (I used the google map polygon api to render some of the geometries as comparison)

[Screenshot Here](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v350/eterna2/googlemap_zpsdshxmhdh.png)

I am totally at a loss, what might be the reason for this distortion?

I am suspecting that the single precision in the shader is giving rise to the error. So I am wondering if there is any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug this piece of code and diagnose the cause of the issue. I would suggest you using the [CanvasLayer](https://github.com/brendankenny/CanvasLayer) library that hides all these concrete details of specifying the coordinates you want to draw the polygon. Rather you would be able to focus on your app code and functionality. The performance will be better in terms of projected image.

Comment: Thanks for the link. My current code is very similar to CanvasLayer but it doesn't help. My main problem is the projection, which is not addressed in CanvasLayer either - he is using world coordinate for his plotting. I need to project LatLng and various geo-coordinates into google world coordinates. And this resulted in some distorted as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: I cannot use the google map API to do the projection because I have a huge number of geometries, and javascript aren't fast enough to do the projection realtime, and u waste bandwidth pushing the updated coordinates into the shader at each render loop.